# Different Flush Stories

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Say we’re given a standard 52 card deck. We can enumerate all possible combinations for a flush (5 cards with the same suit) with the story: pick a suit, then pick 5 cards in that suit.

$$\binom{4}{1} \binom{13}{5}$$

Alternatively, we could pick one card, and then pick the next of the same suit, and pick the next, and so on. Then to compensate that any ordering of a result is the same divide by 5!.

$$\binom{52}{1} \binom{12}{1} \binom{11}{1} \binom{10}{1} \binom{9}{1} / 5!$$

We could condense the above into a simpler statement: pick the first card, and then pick four remaining from the same suit, but it looks like there's an extra factor of 5 that needs to be removed:

$$\binom{52}{1} \binom{12}{4}$$

What's the reasoning behind that five? I assume this has something to do with over counting the position of the first card relative to the other four?

Comment: The second method distinguishes the "first" card selected from the others. Any of the five cards in the flush could have been picked "first", so each possible hand is counted five times.